# To sum a column of dictionary conditioned on another column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
+---------------------------+-------+
|Maps                       |   B   |
+---------------------------+-------+
|Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)|   1   |
|Map(a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 3)|   1   |
|Map(a -> 2, b -> 4, d -> 6)|   2   |
+---------------------------+-------+
```

To get the sum of Maps which shares same "B" value.
Expected:

```
+---------------------------+-------+
|Maps                       |   B   |
+---------------------------+-------+
|Map(a -> 2, b -> 5, c -> 6)|   1   |
|Map(a -> 2, b -> 4, d -> 6)|   2   |
+---------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(F.explode("Maps"), F.col("B"))\
        .groupBy("key", "B")\
        .sum("value")
```